# My Google+ Button And The Number Of Clicks?

Tags: google-plus

I have the google+ on my website and, up until yesterday morning, I had 350+ clicks, and then for no apparent reason the numbers started to drop by about 2-3 a minute and they keep falling? Does anyone know what's causing this problem? My website is http://www.dj-to-hire.com

Answer (score 0):

There are some issues with your markup, but they do not seem to be impacting the +1 button.

First, let's address the minor issues. Your `<link rel="canonical" href="index.html" />` should contain a full URL to the target page. It should probably look something like `<link rel="canonical" href="http://www.dj-to-hire.com" />`

That does not seem to be causing the issue, though, because you're explicitly specifying `http://www.dj-to-hire.com` in the `href` attribute of your +1 button markup. I'm going to do some digging to see if I can figure out what's up. I'll update this answer once I have something to report :)

In the mean time, can you please check the [Webmaster Tools](http://www.google.com/webmasters/tools/) dashboard to see if the +1 count it reports still agrees with your button?

Comment: According to my webmaster tools, the +1 count was 350 on the 8th May and then it fell to 42 the following day. It is currently at 21 and has been since the 13th of May. Can't figure it out at all. Thanks for your help so far.